# Is there a UIImagePicker for the Mac Desktop

Tags: cocoa, uiimagepickercontroller

I have found Apple's example app ImagePicker that uses IKImagePicker, but it appears that in Lion it has been removed. Is there an alternative to this - or how would I prompt users to select an image to use within my app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want [IKPictureTaker](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/IKImagePicker_Class/).

> The IKPictureTaker class represents a panel that allows users to choose images by browsing the file system. The picture taker panel provides an Open Recent menu, supports image cropping, and supports taking snapshots from an iSight or other digital camera.